# NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction results in a flipped image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I use:

```
[iconImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(cellFrame.origin.x+5,yOffset+3,cellFrame.size.height-6, cellFrame.size.height-6)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,[iconImage size].width, [iconImage size].height)
                    operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
                     fraction:1.0];
```

to draw some images in the NSOutlineView cells, the images are vertically flipped upside down. How can I fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: yeah I also need this to work in 10.5-10.8 and the set flipped doesn't affect drawing in 10.8, also i thought that i remembered setting a source image with a negative height would cause a flip, that doesn't seem to work here either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the method

```
- (void)drawInRect:(NSRect)dstSpacePortionRect
          fromRect:(NSRect)srcSpacePortionRect
         operation:(NSCompositingOperation)op
          fraction:(CGFloat)requestedAlpha
    respectFlipped:(BOOL)respectContextIsFlipped
             hints:(NSDictionary *)hints
```

along with `- (void)lockFocusFlipped:(BOOL)flipped`

to draw the image upside down. From the [NSImage Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) manual.

Comment: Thanks, I can use your method to flip the image back, but isn't strange that it is already vertically flipped when I draw it ? I just want to draw the original image as it is.

Comment: It's not that strange because CoreGraphics and Carbon puts the origin at the upper left, while Cocoa (App Kit) and OpenGL use Lower Left for the origin. As in all things in code, it depends on the interpretation. For Example the value 0x20 by itself is meaningless. If interpreted to an integer it is 32, if interpreted as ASCII it is a space.

Comment: Also, pass `NSZeroRect` as the `srcSpacePortionRect` and the full image will be drawn. Saves you having to do `NSMakeRect(0,0,[iconImage size].width, [iconImage size].height)`.

Comment: I have a problem: your method is only available since OSX 10.6, and I need it for OSX 10.5 as well. Do you know how can I flip my image in OSX 10.5 ?

Comment: I'm using the deprecated setFlipped: method for OSX 10.5

Comment: `BOOL wasFlipped = [image isFlipped]; [image setFlipped:YES]; [image drawInRect ...]; [image setFlipped:wasFlipped];` ... OR ... You can just change your image to use the TIFF format, then it's for some reason drawing correctly in all versions of Mac OS X (this is probably what one could call a convenience-bug).